# Binary tree insertion method C++

Tags: c++, printing, tree, binary, insertion

```
struct node {
    person * data;
    node * left, * right;

    node(person * p) {
        data = p; left = NULL; right = NULL;
    }
};

class tree {
    protected:
        node * root;
    public:
        tree() {
            root = NULL;
        }

        tree(person * p) {
            root = new node(p);
        }

        void insert(person * p) {
            if(root == NULL) {
                root = new node(p);
                return;
            }
            node * curr = root;
            while(true) {
                if(p->last < curr->data->last) {
                    if(curr->left == NULL) {
                        curr->left = new node(p);
                        return;
                    }
                    curr = curr->left;
                } else {
                    if(curr->right == NULL) {
                        curr->right = new node(p);
                        return;
                    }
                    curr = curr->right;
                }
            }
        }

        void insert(node * & n, person * p) {
            if(n == NULL) {
                n = new node(p);
                return;
            }
            if(p->last < n->data->last)
                insert(n->left, p);
            else
                insert(n->right, p);            
        }

        void insert(person * p) {
            insert(root, p);
        }
        void print(node * n) {
            if(n == NULL)
                return;
            print(n->left);
            cout << n->data->ss << " " << n->data->bday << " "<< n->data->first << ", " << n->data->last << " " << n->data->zip << "\n";
            print(n->right);
        }

        void print() {
            print(root);
        }
};
```

I have looked up other implementations of BST insertions and my logic follows the other threads I've seen. Root is set to NULL in a constructor When I use my print function it prints out random values, not the info that is stored with the person type. In my code I have the two methods of insertion I tried. I've also included my print functions in case there is something wrong there. The printout I get back from my print function almost seems like it displaying the memory address of the contents, but some of the info is missing. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What are the results from debugging?  I highly recommend drawing the tree as you traverse it with the debugger.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can conclusively determine the problem, but only guess, at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've modified my code so that I type in the info I want it to store and then it immediately prints it back out at me. Funny enough my debugger tells me nothing, whether I'm inserting a single piece of info vs the file I want to read in.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. In my person struct, I was naming the parameters of the constructor the same as the variables in the struct. Apparently c++ doesn't like when that's done. Changing the names of the constructor parameters to something else fixed the problem.

Old:

```
person(int ssn, int bday, string first, string last, int zip) {
        ssn = ssn; bday = bday; first = first; last = llast; zip = zip; 
    }
```

New:

```
person(int s, int b, string f, string l, int z) {
        ssn = s; bday = b; first = f; last = l; zip = z; 
    }
```

Comment: If you had used [initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) then it wouldn't hurt that the names of constructor parameters and class member variables are equal: `person(int ssn, int bday, string first, string last, int zip): ssn(ssn), bday(bday), first(first), last(last), zip(zip) { }`. Please, note that initializers replace default construction of member variables (which the compiler would add implicitly otherwise) and should be preferred over assignment in constructors body.